# LibGdx how to get the color of a pixel of a texture?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, pixel

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for days now, and all I've been trying to do is to get the pixel of a point (x,y) of a texture.

The texture class has a method that gives the user access to TextureData from which you can use #getPixel(x,y) to get the color of a pixel at those coordinates.

However, using TextureData, for some brilliant unknown reason, flips the image, so that the point (x,y) you are looking at is actually the (x, height-y) - or so it seems.

When I try and invert it by checking #getPixel(x, height - y), it seems to be off-place.

[image]

The red image above is the texture drawn using SpriteBatch. The white image is drawing the non-transparency of every single pixel of the texture. The two textures should be on top of one another.

It seems like it is unfeasible to get a specific pixel of a coordinate without adding arbitrary values to the (x,y) coords to get it to be placed exactly over the original image.

Comment: could you please share some of your code?

Comment: The getPixel methods in Pixmap work correctly. Something is wrong with your code so you will have to show your code for anyone to be able to help. Also, please don't open multiple questions about the same thing. Edit your original question.